# How to represent 3 options in a UML Activity Diagram?

Tags: uml, system, diagram, flowchart, activity-diagram

I have a situation where 3 options are presented to a user by a system:

1. Open PDF1.
2. Open PDF2.
3. Proceed.

The system instructs the user to read the PDFs, but doesn't enforce it.
So they're free to just click the proceed button and move on to the next screen.

I drew the following diagrams, but I feel like I've got it wrong somehow.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That's not correct this way. Your 2nd attempt isn't better at all. The bars will create parallel flows, but since you join them immediately it's actually a no-op in the first case. The bar will not be reached since it waits for 3 tokens where only one can actually arrive. In the 2nd case will never continue after the join since it only gets one token from the `Provides...` action but need 3 to continue.

Here's a cut part of what you need to do:

[image]

There's a merge node at first to capture the tokens coming from either the action on top or from the two left ones. After there there are two decisions going guarded to the actions at the left. The can be continued to the top (guard `[read next]`) or to the bottom (guard `[acknowledge]`). That way the user can repeat reading (or skip it completely) until he passes the `Acknowledge` action. There's a final merge node preceding that action.

Note that the `read/ack` guards should appear twice for each flow to make it a machine readable model. The texts here are just overlaid but a human can understand it anyway.

Comment: Thanks. But what about the swim-lanes? Also, I added a second attempt before reading this. Is it any better? Is this the kind of thing where more than one way is acceptable, or is it governed by strict rules?

Comment: Your 2nd attempt is even worse. Try to think of your "swim lanes" (they should rather be Partitions) as at the same locations in my excerpt.

Comment: Okay. Is there only one correct answer with these things?

Comment: Also, I've never seen guards in activity diagrams before, is that normal? I feel like what I've been taught is wrong.

Comment: A guard is what it says: it lets a token only pass if the parole is correct. And yes, this is the way you model it. You might arrange it differently, but basically this is it. E.g. you could use a single decision with 2 guarded outputs rather then 2 consecutive ones.

Comment: Further, what you use in your diagram is the **name** of the flow. But the guard condition is actually written embraced in square brackets.

Comment: I see. I thought the guards were the vertical lines (above `Read PDF1` and below `Read PDF2`). If the partitions are still in the same place, that seems odd. Because it appears as if the System is the one making decisions, instead of the Student. Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Well, I drew only flows. So the horizontal "bars" are just flows. It's just that 2 flows are overlaid. Displacing them would make it ugly. Having PDF1 and 2 on left and right of the decisions would make it more readable but would not fit in your partition scheme.

Comment: Would you be my UML tutor? I feel like you're much better than my lecturer.

Comment: I don't know your tutor, but quite often I find questions here that let me doubt in UML education in general ;-) Just ask your questions here. There are a lot of smart people which can answer all sorts of questions.